# Angular, using angular material switch in a bootstrap modal (aria label issue)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

I am building angular app using angular, bootstrap, and angular-material. Specificlly I'm using bootstrap-ui for angular's modals - seend here http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. I have had no problems with angular-material until now, when I place the material switches in a bootstrap modal (in the template) I am getting an aria error and they are not working. 
I'm using these switches (https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.switch)

I just have it in the body of the modal like this to test it at first -

```
<div class="modal-body">
 <md-switch ng-model="data" aria-label="Switch 1">
    Switch 1
  </md-switch>
</div>
```

The switches work fine outside of the modal but when I open the modal the console spits out the error like so (and the switch does not work) :

```
ARIA: Attribute " aria-label ", required for accessibility, is missing on node <div class="md-container" md-ink-ripple="" md-ink-ripple-checkbox=""><div class="md-off"></div><div class="md-on"></div></div>
```

I'm not sure what to do becasue there is an aria label on the switch itself, may because the boostrap ui makes a new controller for the modal itself, it's getting confused, or not getting the proper injections? Would appreciate any help. thanks for reading

Comment: Try using angular-materials `$mdDialog` instead. Also why are you trying to mix them? Just pick one.

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker or a Codepen of this issue? However, I agree that using the $mdDialog instead of Bootstrap should clear things up.

Comment: @ajmajmajma can you tell us how you solved this problem. I need to use bootstrap's dialog since $mdDialog is not suitable for my requirements (I need scrolling outside the modal) -- can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Comment: Can you please adapt/modify http://codepen.io/z00bs/pen/bpjrBw so we can reproduce your issue?